# Meta keywords and descriptions plugin for manually editing meta for each page/post

Tags: custom-field, customization, post-meta

Can anyone recommend a simple plugin that allows me to add/edit meta tags for keywords and description on each page of my wordpress site? Just something that adds the fields to the page editor would be ideal. Not looking for SEO megapack or whatever.

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simple solution would be to paste this snippet of code in your theme's functions.php file :

```
add_action('wp_head','keywords_and_desc');
function keywords_and_desc(){
    global $post;
    if (is_single()||is_page()){
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_keywords',true) != '') 
            echo    '<meta content="'.get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_keywords',true).'" name="keywords">';
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_description',true) != '') 
            echo    '<meta content="'.get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_description',true).'" name="description">';
    }
}
```

And the just add keywords and description using the built in custom fields on a new/edit post/page screen, name the keywords field `my_keywords` and the description field `my_description`.

or you can use a very lightweight and simple plugin called [**Simple Meta Tags**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-meta-tags/)